# HowTo create Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSQL Cluster with terraform

Tags: postgresql, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create an *Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSQL Cluster*. The terraform resource provider `azurerm` has a resource `azurerm_cosmosdb_account` which does not seem to reflect the attributes of the web base wizard of Azure (e.g. *PostgreSQL version* or *Scale* are missing from terraform)

I did the following but it was not successful as the requested resource type has a quota of zero for my location. This error does not pop up if I create the cluster via web.

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "main" {
  name                = "cospos-main"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "Parse"

  enable_free_tier              = true
  enable_automatic_failover     = false
  public_network_access_enabled = false

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level = "Strong"
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database" "db" {
  name                = "sqldb-db"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.main.resource_group_name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.main.name

  autoscale_settings {
    max_throughput = 1000
  }
}
```

Error information hints at quota which I get in web console if I create *Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible servers*.

```
{\"code\":\"ServiceUnavailable\",\"message\":\"Sorry, we are currently experiencing high demand in Germany West Central region, and cannot fulfill your request at this time Tue, 22 Nov 2022 11:26:12 GMT. To request region access for your subscription, please follow this link https://aka.ms/cosmosdbquota for more details on how to create a region access request."}
```

Manually I can create the Comos DB cluster just fine.

The values for `kind`and `consistency_level` are pretty much a guess as the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account) does not really enlighten me.

Any hints on how to create a cluster with terraform?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @kavyaSaraboju I added the error description.

Comment: I looks like it is simply not supported yet: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/19375

Comment: did you check the link to see if you can up your quota? https://aka.ms/cosmosdbquota